# Component Preloading before opening it

Tags: react-native

This is a conceptional question, in this case a component is a screen, if that makes sense

Is there a good solution for fluently preloading a component? What I mean by that is perhaps calling a portion of a component, before opening up the view

an example of this is say, snapchat stories, when greyed out on press will simply load. The second press then opens up the view. Essentially allows you to preload before then navigation to the view

Is this a Redux task? Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some concepts are mangled in your mind. What you are trying to achieve is not to preload components, rather run logic before drawing anything on the screen OR preloading some media. Therefore, what you need to do is not to preload anything, but to seperate your logic from your view (let's say video data from showing video itself), retrieve / prepare data (download video for example) and after it is ready show your component.

Also, if what you are trying to preload is just media, you should checkout `react-preload`.

Comment: would you use redux to set this off?, basically i want to have a button that on press downloads information and performs calculations, and then on the second press view the data in a screen or so

Comment: It truly doesn't matter, you can even handle it in your onPress function, set it to redux / mobx / state, and on second press pass it as prop, retrieve it from redux / mobx. It is entirely dependent on your app's structure.

Comment: but when seperating logic from the view, once your in the view you might need to access that logic as well. Does that make sense?

Comment: Best way of handling such a thing would be to move it out of your views into your stores, redux in this case. More seperation you can achieve, easier to write / maintain your app will become.

Comment: okay, is redux able to be 'comeponetized', this is kinda a confusing question but I mean in the sense that say i had 10 different instances of this component, am i able to have 10 different redux stores

Comment: I know that it can be done on mobx, however I haven't tried something similar in redux. Assuming you have an array of rows, just add a preload field that is by default null there and a status that can be loading, initial, ready. Manage each row by using that, I think that would be easier.

Comment: Do you know what this would be called with mobx? I am trying to figure it out.. basically trying to dynamically create mobx stores for each component.. can't for the life of me figure out what it would be called though

Comment: In mobx, you create a class as store definition. After that, by doing ```new StoreClass()``` you create a new store. Import class definition and in your constructor create a new store, if you want something like that.